# Distance between objects is kept constant for rigid body

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I tried this tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY and I'm stuck by creating the chain correctly (I'm pretty new to Blender). I think **the problem is that the chain links keep the same distance when falling. This leads to the chain falling in it's entirety like a stick (see screenshot a few seconds after begin of the simulation) and not falling into each other like the tutorial suggests (at 02:08).**

I think that I carefully followed the tutorial, created the chain in the same way as suggested and changed the rigid body collision shape to mesh and copied it from active for all chain links. I tried centering the origin to center of mass but that doesn't help.

The blender version in the tutorial from 2014 is different to mine which is v2.78, so some option seem to be new or different. Maybe that is the problem (or I just got something different wrong). In this context the `source` below `shape` does not show up in the tutorial (and is set to `Deform` as default). What am I missing?

[image: chain falling like a stick, the chain links seems connected.]

Comment: Making a new project and following the instructions carefully again worked. But I still don't know what I accidentaly did to break it.